# Using MySQL query in selecting room availability

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I had this database structure in a hotel reservation in terms of room availability

below is my table of `room`

```
room_num    roomtype     
101         Single    
102         Single    
103         Single    
111         Deluxe    
112         Deluxe   
113         Deluxe    
114         Deluxe    
115         Deluxe    
116         Deluxe    
121         Superior  
122         Superior
```

and the table below is `room_booked` which is records booked room numbers

`dor` is checkin date and `dco` is date checkout

```
room_num        dor         dco
  111        2014-06-01  2014-06-06
  112        2014-06-01  2014-06-06
  113        2014-06-01  2014-06-06
  114        2014-06-01  2014-06-06
  115        2014-06-01  2014-06-06
  116        2014-06-01  2014-06-06
  112        2014-05-18  2014-05-21
  113        2014-08-01  2014-08-04
```

In this case, all of Deluxe room are booked from `2014-06-01` to `2014-06-06`. Then I selected Deluxe room available from 2014-06-01 to 2014-06-06 by using this MySQL code below

```
SELECT
    room.room_num
FROM
    room
LEFT JOIN
    room_booked ON room_booked.room_num = room.room_num
WHERE
    (
        (
            dor IS NULL AND dco IS NULL
        )
        OR (
            -- wished booking date is before DOR
            '2014-06-06' < dor
            -- OR wished booking date is after DCO
            OR '2014-06-01' >=  dco
        )
    )
    -- room type
    AND roomtype = 'Deluxe'
```

However it shows Deluxe room no. 112 and 113 which is booked before and after selected date range above instead of 0 or fully booked. Is there any solution to fix this code?

Comment: do you want to get the deluxrooms between those two dates or what?

Comment: Change `left join` to `inner join`

Comment: I want to get deluxe room from 2014-06-01 to 2014-06-06. However it shows deluxe room that also booked in May and August, instead of showing 0 or fully booked. I had changed to inner join but there is no change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to check both dates for check in and check out:

```
SELECT
    room.room_num
FROM
    room
WHERE
  roomtype = 'Deluxe' AND
  room.room_num not in 
  (
    SELECT
      room_booked.room_num
    FROM
      room_booked
    WHERE
      (room_booked.dor<='2014-06-1' and room_booked.dco>='2014-06-1')
      OR
      (room_booked.dor<'2014-06-06' and room_booked.dco>='2014-06-06')
      OR
      (room_booked.dor>='2014-06-01' and room_booked.dco<'2014-06-06')
   )
```

re-Edited answer and created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68de5c/1) for testing

Comment: I've tested in my case but it still the same. The room number 112 and 113 still appears

Comment: @user3573666 you are right multiple records in room_booked doubles results, see update